# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia NotFoundError in Linux

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, webrtc

### Versions affected

Chromium 60.0.3112.89 (Developer Build) Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 9.4 (32-bit)
and adapter.js v6.3.2

### Description

When trying getUserMedia() I get this NotFoundError but it works fine if I use Firefox.
If I use enumerateDevices I can see a list of mediaDevices like: 

`MediaDeviceInfo {deviceId: "XXX", kind: "videoinput", label: "mmal service 16.1", groupId: ""}`

So seems related with the chrome not recognizing the camera driver.

### Steps to reproduce

Just trying to run the basic get user media demo: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/

I believe that *This issue not only happens when adapter.js is used* but I would appreciate some guidance here!

Thanks!

Comment: gUM should not return a MediaDeviceInfo list, enumerateDevices does this. So please be specific about what you are experiencing. From where is this error thrown?

Comment: `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: false,
      video: {
        "min":{"width":"720","height":"360"},
        "max":{"width":"1920","height":"1080"}
      }
    })
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(function(e) {
      alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
    });` The same code works perfec when using Chrome and Firefox in my windows machine

Comment: Would be good to include it in an [edit] to your question. What if you remove the videoConstraints and let it be auto `getUserMedia({ video: true})`?

Comment: chrome://media-internals has a video capture tab which lists supported devices. If your device does not show up you might want to file a bug on crbug.com.
Also try not using constraints, even though if the camera does not support this resolution the error should be different.